# Opening an EXE Application after a timeout with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is a bit tricky to explain, but let me try.

I have 6 `UserForm` in a VBA Project. 
The execution of the macro will hide each form and show the next one in line. 
In the first UserForm, on the click event of the `Next` button there is some code that modifies the currently opened Excel file, then hides the current `UserForm`, show the next one AND open `saplogon.exe` after a 5 second timeout.

It all works perfectly, BUT saplogon doesn't open until after i closed the 6th `UserForm`. Whereas i want it to open in the second, which is where the code to open the file is at.

I'm not really sure what i'm doing wrong. Following is the code i use in `UserForm1`.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'My Code
UserForm2.Show

Dim sFullPathToExecutable As String

sFullPathToExecutable = "C:\Program Files(x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Shell sFullPathToExecutable

End Sub
```

Why isn't the EXE opening at `UserForm2`?

Thanks!

Comment: `UserForm2.Show` is modal by default and stop the execution of the function waiting for Userform2 to do it's stuff and close/hide. You have to either use non modal userform or change the way you call the userforms one after the other.

Comment: or maybe you can use only one userform with a multipage control?

Comment: Hi! That Multipage control idea sounds interesting. Maybe i'll switch to that later but for now i just kinda put the UserForm2.Show line after the code to open the file after your comment. That works fine. Thank you for the help.!

Comment: Even better, i moved the code to open the EXE in to the `UserForm2_Activate()` event. It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance someone else find themselves in a similar situation where you have to open a program in the background and show the next userform without losing focus on excel, Place the `shell("location of the .exe")` line into your next userform's Activate event:-

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
End Sub
```